# Alternative ways to convert data table to customized XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datatable

Is there a way i can create an XML from datatable without using

1. A `StringWriter`:

   ```
   System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
   yourDataTable.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema, true);
   ```

   Doesn't work well for me as it gives descendants as column headers. I want first row as descendants.
2. Iterating over DataColumns and DataRows.

I was reading about LINQ-to-DataTable and LINQ-to-XML .

Can LINQ query help me?

Comment: here's a link to the XDocument class, It's the Linq to XML class  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using the `XmlDocument` class to generate XML

```
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

        XmlElement rootElement = xDoc.CreateElement("Root");
        XmlElement customElement = xDoc.CreateElement("customElement");
        XmlAttribute xAtt = xDoc.CreateAttribute("customAttribute");
        xAtt.Value = "attval";

        customElement.Attributes.Append(xAtt);
        rootElement.AppendChild(customElement);
        xDoc.AppendChild(rootElement);
```

The linq to xml library `XDocument` follows a similar model.   you should look at the documentation and make use of it.