# XML Writer stored results to string

Tags: c#, xml, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative ways to convert data table to customized XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297843/alternative-ways-to-convert-data-table-to-customized-xml)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Product_ID", Type.GetType("System.String")));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Product_Name", Type.GetType("System.String")));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("product_Price", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
fillRows("hello1", dt, "product1", 1111);
fillRows("hello2", dt, "product2", 2222);
fillRows("hello3", dt, "product3", 3333);
fillRows("hello4", dt, "product4", 4444);


var xmlColumnZero = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(col => col[0].ToString()).ToArray() ; // row 0 turnovermultiplieer
var xmlRowZero = dt.Columns;
string firstColumnHeader = dt.Columns[0].ToString();
// XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("employees.xml");
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("Employees");

// XmlElement first = xmldoc.CreateElement("Order");
//xmldoc.AppendChild(first);
foreach (DataColumn dc  in dt.Columns ) 
{

    if (dc.ToString() == firstColumnHeader) continue;
    string firstcol = dc.ToString();
    writer.WriteStartElement(firstcol);
    // XmlElement colRoot = xmldoc.CreateElement(firstcol);
    //first.AppendChild(colRoot);
    for (int i = 0 ; i <dt.Rows.Count && i< xmlColumnZero.Length ; i++)
    {
        string firstrow = xmlColumnZero[i];
        string dtagaga = dt.Rows[i][dc].ToString();
        writer.WriteElementString(firstrow, dtagaga);
       // XmlElement rowRoot = xmldoc.CreateElement(firstrow, dtagaga);
        //colRoot.AppendChild(rowRoot);


    }
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();
```

I want the XMl to be stored into a string while i am creating XMLWriter.

Is there another way i can create xml out of the table

XML should look like

The xml writer method stores everything into an xml file in the program location. Would prefer a string to be saved

```
<Employees>
<Product_Name>
<hello1>product1</hello1>
hello2>product2</hello2>
hello3>product3</hello3>
hello4>product4</hello4>
</product_name>
<product_Price>
<hello1>1111</hello1>
hello2>2222</hello2>
hello3>3333</hello3>
hello4>4444</hello4>
</product_Price>
</Employees>
```

Comment: What does `fillRows` do?

Comment: Did you intentionally put malformed XML in your question? I think that is confusing the issue.

Comment: If you want a string saved why are you using an XmlWriter?  Post an example of what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use overloaded method [`XmlWriter.Create(StringBuilder output)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66dybzaw.aspx) to create xml string. In this case all output will be written to `StringBuilder` instead of file:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder);
//... build xml here

string xml = builder.ToString();
```

Also you can write xml to `MemoryStream` with [`XmlWriter.Create(Stream output)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x972ksd0.aspx).

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
// ... build xml here

stream.Position = 0;
string xml = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
```

**UPDATE**

Extension method below will generate your xml string. By default it uses first column as element names, but you can pass any column index for column with meta data. Also I use table name to generate "Employees" tag, so provide name when you create data table `DataTable dt = new DataTable("Employees");`.

```
public static string ToXml(this DataTable table, int metaIndex = 0)
{
    XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
        new XElement(table.TableName,
            from column in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
            where column != table.Columns[metaIndex]
            select new XElement(column.ColumnName,
                from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                select new XElement(row.Field<string>(metaIndex), row[column])
                )
            )
        );

    return xdoc.ToString();
}
```

Usage is very simple:

```
string xml = dt.ToXml();
```

Output:

```
<Employees>
  <Product_Name>
    <hello1>product1</hello1>
    <hello2>product2</hello2>
    <hello3>product3</hello3>
    <hello4>product4</hello4>
  </Product_Name>
  <product_Price>
    <hello1>111</hello1>
    <hello2>222</hello2>
    <hello3>333</hello3>
    <hello4>444</hello4>
  </product_Price>
</Employees>
```

Comment: Best Approach. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user1650470 welcome :) keep in mind, that xml produced without xml declaration, as you wanted in expected output

Comment: Is it possible to create xml without table name i.e Node <Employees> here . I tried couple of ways but didn't work for me. How should i modify the extension method. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1650470 actually you need root node. It will not be well-formatted xml if you will have several different nodes on top level..

Comment: i dont require for now as i have a function which takes two parameters the root node(table name) and the xml and creates a new xml out of it.

Comment: If not possible i will have to create the function. But if possible i would like to do it in extension method.

Comment: @user1650470 replace `table.TableName` with name, which you will pass as parameter to this extension method. This will generate whole xml for you. Otherwise you will have to deal with list of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) and [create the `XmlWriter` using the `StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66dybzaw.aspx) instead of a file:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb);
writer.WriteStartDocument();
//...
writer.WriteEndDocument();
var myXmlString = sb.ToString(); //myXmlString will contain the XML
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a file

```
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("employees.xml");
```

You can use String stream

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw);
...
...
// sw.ToString(); // string output
```